# What is swapping on my Server

Tags: 16.04, swap

I have been having issue with a server I Manage, and have tried so many different things that I can't even remember the half of them. Right now I am just plain puzzled with the output, maybe someone can help me understand.

When I do free -h it tells me that there is 3.5M of SWAP used, however smem does not list anything in SWAP. This leads me to believe that either it's a memory leak, dead process, or free/smem is telling lies.

By the end of this day the SWAP will have grown and I will en up restarting the server... just to do the same trick all over again in about 7 days.

Anybody have this happen to them before ?

Comment: Look at Memory Hogs - increased swap usage is the system's response to tasks asking for more (and more) memory. Start with `ps`

Comment: The Problem is, that I can't see what is using the swap, hence the Question. If I know what is using swap size, I could limit that process.

Comment: Processes don't "use the swap", they jusr request more (and more) memory, thus the recommendation to use `ps` to find the processes that are using a lot of memory. `swap` is something the system does, in order to satisfy requests for memory. Read `man ps`, https://superuser.com/questions/398862/linux-find-out-what-process-is-using-all-the-ram